# Storing navigation graphs points in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

On my image I have multiple points which are interconnected each point can have multiple or no connections to another point. I use these points to navigate users around indoors.

Anyhow I'm not at the stage of my project where I'm already adding shortest or path finding algorithms but I do need the table and need it to be optimal for when I start adding navigation portion.

Currently the idea I have is to store each point multiple times and have it reference it self so each entry that has more than one connection would have multiple entries referencing it's self.

That or have two tables:
Points - save points
Connections - save all connections each point has

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you think you will have more data associated with each point (locations maybe?)  You probably will.

For example:

```
Point: 
x,y, ID

Connection:
Point1_ID, Point2_ID, distance
```